# Generic wireless USB Adapter/ Bluetooth transmitter

Tags: usb, wireless, bluetooth

I recently bought a long HDMI cable to connect my PC to my TV. Works fine, but I have a corded mouse and keyboard. It works, but it is rather inconvenient to drag the cables around. I will propably buy a wireless mouse, but a while ago I bought a rather expensive mechanical keyboard, which I don't want to exchange.

The keyboard has a standard USB 2.0 port, where I usually connect the USB cable. Is there some kind of generic USB adapter, so that I can connect this keyboard wireless to my PC?

As a bonus: I also have an XBOX One Controller and Microsoft decided not to deliver some kind of conectivity, except bluetooth, which I can't use on my PC. It would be amazing if there would be a solution I could use for both, controller and keyboard (not neccessarily at the same time). The controller has a standard USB 2.0 Micro-USB port I could use for that. Some kind of wireless hub with small USB connectors in different formats or something similar would be cool. I don't know if there is something like this.

Additional question after I browsed some online shops: I have found some low cost bluetooth receivers I could plug into my computer. With that I could use the controller wireless. But they are just receivers for bluetooth devices. Is there such a connector I could plug into my keyboard to make it a bluetooth device? This would be the simplest solution from my point of view.

But also a question regarding bluetooth: When this would work, like I imagine and I connect the keyboard via bluetooth, could I still use the keyboard pre-boot? Like in the BIOS?

Just realised that I would have a problem with powering the keyboard... any suggestions?

Comment: Is it an Xbox One S controller, or an Xbox One controller?

Comment: It's an XBox One Controller.
I realised, that because of the power problem I won't find a solution like I wanted. I just bought a wireless mouse, a bluetooth adapter and a longer USB cable. Not that convenient, but it will do

Comment: Normal Xbox One controllers don't have Bluetooth support, only the Xbox One S.